# How to handle multiple marionette CollectionViews sharing the same collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've got a single page that needs to show multiple little boxes of the same collection sorted different ways.

Is there an event I can use to sort the collection just before rendering and use the same collection in all of the CollectionViews? Or should I make N copies of the collection sorted different ways and wire up the events myself?

I'd really like for all of the views to update when I add/remove an item from the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CollectionView allows for a custom [viewComparator](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-viewcomparator) option if you want
>   your CollectionView's children to be rendered with a different sort
>   order than the underlying Backbone collection uses.